How to confirm a download
When I download Ubuntu the file is named UNCONFIRMED... and Etcher will not install it on an attached USB drive. How can I confirm the file so that Etcher will install it?

Please [edit] your question and give us some context. What are you downloading exactly? Where are you downloading it from? What is etcher, do you mean https://etcher.balena.io/? Do you get any errors?

You probably need to wait. UNCONFIRMED is the filename chrome gives to a download when it hasn't been fully downloaded. As the iso file is pretty big (4-5 GB) it may take a long time at downloading. Sit back and relax. Also, don't close chrome while the file is downloading.

https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0   CONFIRMED is something specific to your type of download; I get none of that using zsync, wget or any tool I use to download (which is usually not a browser, and not google-chrome)

This question is similar to: How to download an ISO file for Ubuntu?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
